# salesforce trigger or schedule invoke after a period of time

Tags: salesforce, scheduler

I looked into salesforce trigger and scheduler is there any way i can create a scheduler to repeat itself for an hour or the time i configured in the screen.
Schedule should stop automatically after the given time.
inputs will be

Start time
 
Frequency
End time(This where the schedule should stop executing)

if you can provide a sample code will be great